# Function calls function in Go

Tags: go, scope

```
package main

var a string

func main() {
   a = "G"
   print(a)
   f1()
}

func f1() {
   a := "O"
   print(a)
   f2()
}

func f2() {
   print(a)
}
```

I think `f2` will be in `f1`'s block when call `f2` in `f1`, so the output will be `GOO`, but the output is `GOG` instead.

> The scope of a type identifier declared inside a function begins at the identifier in the TypeSpec and ends at the end of the innermost containing block.  -- From https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope

What are containing blocks inside a function?

Why another function is not containing block?

Comment: Containing block here is a block where the function is defined, not from which it is called. Most blocks are framed in `{ }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `f1` creates a new, local variable `a` which *shadows* the global variable `a`:

```
func f1() {
   a := "O"
   print(a)
   f2()
}
```

That variable is scoped to `f1`. Any function it calls has its own scope, no scope change within `f1` has any impact on any other function it calls (excepting closures). So, when `f2` accesses `a`, it is accessing the *global* `a`. Otherwise, determining behavior would be nearly impossible because it would depend entirely on the calling context which can vary between different calls to the same function. If you want to pass some value to a function, pass it as a parameter.

Comment: So a funtion's scope is the `current global scope` + `current function's own scope'`? If you want to change the scope of a called function, you can either change the global scope or the scope of the called function.

Comment: You can't change a called function's scope. You can modify existing global variables' values, and a function (however it is called) can create new local variables, which may shadow global variables.

Answer (score 1):

In the same paragraph it also says this:

> An identifier declared in a block may be redeclared in an inner block.
>   While the identifier of the inner declaration is in scope, it denotes
>   the entity declared by the inner declaration.

Thus the answer should be "GOG".

Answer (score 1):

Containing blocks in function are any control structures, like e.g. `if`, `for` or `switch`.

Functions can be containing blocks for variables. In your example `f1` is a containing block, as it redeclares `a` and shadows the global declaration.

`f2` is not in `f1`s block. They are declared at the same level. But you could define a function inside another function:

```
func f1() {
    a := "a1" // f1 is containig block for a
    f2 := func () {
        // a is visible here, too
        b := "b" // f2 is containing block for b, only visible in f2
    }
}
```

Comment: A [function is a containing block](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope) whether or not it declares or shadows any variables. Your latter example is called a [closure](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals).

Comment: I did not say otherwise, but I changed my answer to be a bit clearer. Thanks for your input.

The whole example contains a closure, but it is not a very good example for a closure. That topic is a bit beside the point.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this question, I think you should first realize [What happens when a function is called](http://qr.ae/TU1in0).

When `f1` call `f2`, `f1`'s return address, `f2`'s parameters and locals will be added to the stack. So `f2` can only visit its locals and current globals.

The `a := "O"` in `f1` only updates the locals of `f1` and doesn't affect the globals. So `f2` will read `a`(the value is same `G`) from globals.

In summarize, when call `f2()` in `f1`, the `f2()` is in `f1`'s block, but when enter `f2`, `f1`'s block  has no concern with `f2`.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating a new variable 'a' in f1()
try this :

```
package main

var a string

func main() {
    a = "G"
    print(a)
    f1()
}

func f1() {
    a = "O"
    print(a)
    f2()
 }

func f2() {
    print(a)
}
```

by removing ':' before '=' you will refer to the global variable